# set timeout when update zustand state

Tags: reactjs, zustand

I try to update zustand state use set timeout without other hooks

```
const useCustom = create(set => ({
  isAction: false,
  onAction: value =>
    set(prev => {
      return { isAction: true };
      setTimeout(() => {
        return { isAction: false };
      }, 100);
    }),
}));
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Nothing after a `return` will be executed. Your IDE should highlight as much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `setTimeout` in this way , it should work as you expect

```
const useCustom = create(set => ({
    isAction: false,
    onAction: () => {
       set({ isAction: true });
       setTimeout(() => {
         set((state) => ({ isAction: false }));
       }, 100);
    },
}));
```